# openJPA batch update pattern

Tags: jpa, openjpa, karaf

I need to update thousands of Entities and the logic can not be put into a SQL statement.  When using non-managed JPA the pattern I use is:

```
long commitThreshold = 100;  // or other appropriate value
try {
  em.beginTransction().begin();
  for(list of entities to be modified) {
      // retrieve current Entity
      // modify current Entity 

      if((++modifiedEntityCount % commitThreshold) == 0) {
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
      }
  }
  if(em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
      em.getTransaction().commit();
  }
catch () {
}
finally {
    // cleanup 
}
```

In a managed environment this results in a

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction management is not available for container managed EntityManagers.
```

What is a good pattern for this type of use case when using container managed transactions and blueprint?  My specific environment is karaf 3.0.5 and openJPA 2.3.x if it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your persistence.xml configuration to use statement batching

[OpenJPA Statement batching](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.4.0/apache-openjpa/docs/ref_guide_dbsetup_stmtbatch.html)